# Where to start long running (application lifetime) task

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have a `Blazor` component (server-side, server pre-rendered) that communicates with a backend `gRPC` service to get notifications about the status of a piece of hardware in our system.

The `Blazor` component polls the `gRPC` service for status updates indefinitely (for the entire lifetime of the session at least)

I'm unsure where I can kick off this long running `Task` in the `Blazor` component.

I could for example do something like this:

```
// Ignore the returned Task or make StartLongTaskAsync an async void method.
protected override void OnInitialized( ) =>
    StartLongTaskAsync( );
```

I always hate either ignoring a returned `Task` and I especially hate `async void`...

I considered doing this:

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync( ) =>
    await StartLongTaskAsync( ).ConfigureAwait( false );
```

But I don't think that the `OnInitialized` methods were intended to never complete.

I could also use the `OnAfterRender` but I'm unsure about the following `MS` blurb concerning this lifetime event:

> OnAfterRender and OnAfterRenderAsync aren't called when prerendering on the server.

I did still test this and found that the `OnAfterRender` event was called multiple times, so I'm unsure about that..

I also considered adding a `debounce` timer which would get called from one of the `OnInitialized` methods. The `Timer` handler would kick off the `StartLongTaskAsync`. This would have the added benefit of the `StartLongTaskAsync` not getting invoked twice from `OnInitialized`. Downside of `async void` but I'm thinking I can't avoid that.

**Note:**
I am deriving from `IDisposable` to cancel the `Task` when the component is `Dispose`d of but I'm omitting all of that noise.

### Question

Where is the best place to start my `StartLongTaskAsync` in a `Blazor` component?

Comment: why not have a background service that keeps running even tho your blazor components aren't mounted?

Comment: @DanielA.White Thats what I'm using the `gRPC` service for. The `gRPC` service handles all the nitty gritty of the `TCP` communication with the `hardware`. When the `Blazor` component in question is initialized it can easily connect/disconnect to the `gRPC` service and get status updates about the hardware.

Comment: What you want is to make a service class available to the whole app that consumes your grpc service, then from the component call the service through a setTimeOut. The service can the perform any cacheing you may need and achieves the polling you need. Websockets and SignalR are your friends here. I had a similar use case and achieved it using this method. The blazor component then only cares that it needs to call the service.

Comment: @RichardBarker Yeah that is essentially what I've done. I wrapped the `gRPC` client using a custom `class` and the `gRPC` factory provided by `MS`. I then inject that in to the `Blazor` component. I kick off the `streaming` call (forgot to mention I wasn't polling in this case) inside of a timer's `event` handler.

Comment: Kick off the streaming at app start. The service class isn't known by the browser (beyond how to get a message to the server to trigger something on it). Let the browser call a 'get' on the service that returns the current value in the stream. I e seperate the concept of the stream from the browser and let it be on the server.